# Angular Subscription called twice

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I have a chain of observables which follow this logic:
getStyles() --> getPrices()

For every config.id in configs, getStyles() returns a style Object, this style Object is passed to getLease where a price is appended to it and is then pushed an array called "style"

```
  getStyles(configs: any) {
      configs.forEach(config => {
           this._APIService.getStyleByID(config.id).subscribe(
                res => {
                    res.config = config;
                    this.getLease(res);
                }
           );
    });

  }

  getLease(style: any): void {
      this._priceService.getPrice().subscribe(
        price => {
            style.price = price;
            this.garage.push(style);
            console.log(this.garage);
        });
  }


}
```

The issue I am experiencing is that there is a duplicate call being made because the style array has 2x as many style objects as it needs to have. The issue being that Angular is calling this._APIService.getStyleByID() twice when I expect it to call once. How do I fix my Observables to only be called once?

Comment: it's calling getStyleByID twice bc it is in a forEach loop inside of getStylesWithoutYear

Comment: @Yeysides it calls it twice for each element in the loop

Comment: well, you are subbed to the changing result of getStylesWithoutYear so it is probably calling multiple times as it's value gets updated. Try using mergeMap then subscribing to the final style.

Comment: @Yeysides Yes, I am calling the same subscription multiple times. How do I use mergemap? For clarity, I'm using subscribe to extract the response and push it to another subscription for the same reason. If I am misusing observables, let me know. Also, if you can elaborate on mergeMap and how my code would look different I'll mark you correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switchMap, it's like mergeMap but it cancels the last request if it changes:

```
  getStylesWithoutYear(): void {
    this._APIService.getStylesWithoutYear()
      .switchMap(styles => {
         styles.years.forEach(year => {
          year.styles.forEach(style => {
              this._APIService.getStyleByID(style.id)
           })
         })
      })
      .subscribe(style => {
        console.log('style', style)
      })
  }
```

Comment: Yeah sorry that's correct, but the styles in this subscribe should have been style

Comment: @Moshe return this.getStyleByID

Comment: @Moshe oh well you can just make it void then, I didn't have any signature at first

Comment: @Moshe so you tried making it void, and it returns in both 'styles.year.forEach' and 'this.getStyleByID'?

Comment: @Moshe ohh so this.getStyleById doesn't return anything. It needs to return an observable or just make w.e it returns observable.

Comment: @Yessides, remember, I want to take the response from getStyleWithoutYear and pass the response to getStyleByID

Comment: @Moshe Ok I understand now, gimme a min to update answer.

Comment: `TS2345:Argument of type '(res: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.`

Comment: @Moshe yeah sorry needs to be void it doesn't return anything

Comment: I tried void also didn't work - the error is highlighting `.switchmap(res => {`

Comment: @Moshe can you try returning 'styles.years.foreach' ?

Comment: @Moshe we're missing {} in styles.years.forEach

Comment: Yeah I added that, didn't solve the problem. I'ts not letting me use "styles", does switchMap return "styles"? because I need the response from getStylesWithoutYear() to pass onto the observable in getStyleById

Comment: @Moshe what do you get when you console.log it?

Comment: I cannot compile, "styles" is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'

Comment: @Moshe so you're saying you removed everything inside of switchMap and did switchMap(styles => console.log('styles', styles) and it yelled at you?

Comment: @YaySides, that is exactly what is happening

Comment: @Moshe just for shits and giggles can you replace switchMap with map or mergeMap?

Comment: @Moshe can you try map(styles => return styles).switchMap(res => console.log("res", res))

Comment: I'm going to revise my question in a different way, maybe then we can solve this mystery together.